# Como expandir intervalo de números com dados?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Como eu faria no excel para expandir uma lista enorme com dados para ao invés de agrupar dados de valores, ele mostrasse o conteúdo no total. Exemplo:

**Gostaria de transformar isso:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nisso:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que será uma lista enorme de valores. Então algo automatizado ajudaria muito.

Comment: A planilha inicial terá sempre esse mesmo padrão?

Comment: @Evert A ideia é ter essa mesma estrutura. O que no máximo poderia ser diferente é que ao invés de ser "1 a 10", poderia ser "1-10" ou coisa parecida. Mas toda a coluna seguirá a mesma lógica.

Comment: Certo, vamos precisar de um VBA para fazer isso... vou tentar postar algo aqui para te ajudar e veja se consegue colocar em produção ai.

Comment: @Evert Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minha sugestão é a seguinte:

1. Criar um código para buscar os números da célula, conforme segue abaixo:

   ```
   Function Extrair_Numero(ByRef TEXTO As String, _
                           Optional ByRef SEQUENCIAL As Integer = 1) As Double
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim COUNT As Integer
   Dim TEMP As String
   Dim RESULTADO As Double

       For i = 1 To Len(TEXTO)

           TEMP = Mid(TEXTO, i, 1)

           If IsNumeric(TEMP) Then
               RESULTADO = RESULTADO & TEMP
           ElseIf RESULTADO > 0 Then
               COUNT = COUNT + 1
               If RESULTADO > 0 And SEQUENCIAL = COUNT Then
                   Extrair_Numero = CDbl(RESULTADO)
                   Exit Function
               ElseIf COUNT > 0 And SEQUENCIAL > COUNT Then
                   RESULTADO = Empty
               End If
           End If

       Next
       Extrair_Numero = CDbl(RESULTADO)
   End Function
   ```

> Esta é uma função que retorna o número a partir de uma *string*, podendo retornar o número em determinada posição, ou sequência.
>
> Exemplo: na *string* "12 13 15 18"
>
> 12 seria o primeiro (1), 13 o segundo (2), 15 o terceiro (3) e assim por diante.

2. Cria um *loop* para copiar seus dados para o destino desejado.

   ```
   Sub Copia_Dados()

   Dim PLANILHA_ORIGEM As String
   Dim PLANILHA_DESTINO As String

   Dim COLUNA_CODIGO As String
   Dim COLUNA_DADOS As String

   Dim CELULA_DESTINO_CODIGO As String
   Dim CELULA_DESTINO_DADOS As String

   Dim rCODIGO As Range
   Dim rDADOS As Range

   Dim rCell As Range

   Dim NUM_INI As Double
   Dim NUM_FIM As Double

   Dim i As Integer

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       ' Define as planilhas
       PLANILHA_ORIGEM = "Plan1"
       PLANILHA_DESTINO = "Plan2"

       ' Define as colunas de código e dados (ORIGEM)
       COLUNA_CODIGO = "A"
       COLUNA_DADOS = "B"

       ' Define as células iniciias para código e dados (DESTINO)
       CELULA_DESTINO_CODIGO = "A1"
       CELULA_DESTINO_DADOS = "B1"

       ' Busca os dados das colunas com códigos e dados
       Set rCODIGO = Sheets(PLANILHA_ORIGEM).UsedRange.Columns(COLUNA_CODIGO)
       Set rDADOS = Sheets(PLANILHA_ORIGEM).UsedRange.Columns(COLUNA_DADOS)

       ' Loop na coluna de código
       For Each rCell In rCODIGO.Cells

           ' Buscas os números da célula
           NUM_INI = Extrair_Numero(rCell.Text, 1)
           NUM_FIM = Extrair_Numero(rCell.Text, 2)

           If NUM_INI < NUM_FIM Then
               For i = NUM_INI To NUM_FIM
                   ' Preenche os dados
                   Sheets(PLANILHA_DESTINO).Range(CELULA_DESTINO_CODIGO).Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = i
                   Sheets(PLANILHA_DESTINO).Range(CELULA_DESTINO_DADOS).Offset(i - 1, 0).Value =                 Sheets(PLANILHA_ORIGEM).Range(COLUNA_DADOS & rCell.Row).Value
               Next
           Else
               MsgBox "Os números '" & rCell.Text & "' informado em '" &         rCell.Address & "' não estão em sequência!", vbInformation, "Erro"
               Exit Sub
           End If
       Next

   End Sub
   ```

> Atente-se para as configurações das variáveis para que os dados sejam transferidos do local de origem desejado para o local de destino.

Tentei deixar o mais abstrato possível.

> No código atual, caso sua sequência não seja contínua, por exemplo 1 ao 10 e depois 30 ao 40, a planilha destino terá um "gap" do 11 ao 29, contudo se desta forma não atender dá pra adaptar algo para não pular as células, ou excluir as células em branco posteriormente.

Esperto ter ajudado!

Comment: Opa! Funcionou aqui! Excelente! Muito obrigado, Evert! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Resposta

#### Extrair Elemento

Primeiro a função de extrair elemento é declarada para extrair os elementos separados por espaço `" "`, em que cada elemento possui um index.

Exemplo.: `1 a 3` na célula A1, com a função `EXTRACTELEMENT("A1",1," ")` a resposta é `1` e para  `EXTRACTELEMENT("A1",2," ")` a resposta é `a`

```
Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
 EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Txt), Separator)(n - 1)
End Function
```

#### Expandir (Código Principal)

Este código não está otimizado e se a planilha for muito grande (mais de 50 mil linhas), pode se tornar lenta.

Os elementos precisam ser em ordem ascendente, por exemplo:

```
+---+---------+
|   |    A    |
+---+---------+
| 1 | 1 a 3   |
| 2 | 6 a 9   |
| 3 | 20 a 23 |
+---+---------+
```

No entanto, se for fora de ordem, um erro ocorre. Por exemplo:

```
+---+---------+
|   |    A    |
+---+---------+
| 1 | 1 a 3   |
| 2 | 20 a 23 |
| 3 | 15 a 9  |
+---+---------+
```

Caso não seja em ordem ascendente, algumas condicionais devem ser adicionadas.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

 Do While y <> 1
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If i - 1 = lastrow Or lastrow = 1 Then y = 1
    For i = 1 To lastrow
       Let Rng = "A" & i
          If IsNumeric(ws.Range(Rng)) = False And ws.Range(Rng).Value <> "" Then
              ele1 = EXTRACTELEMENT(ws.Range(Rng), 1, " ")
              ele2 = EXTRACTELEMENT(ws.Range(Rng), 3, " ")
              On Error Resume Next
              j = ws.Range(Rng).Row
              x = CLng(ele2) - j
              Rows(j & ":" & j + x).Insert
              Z = ws.Cells(j + x + 1, 2)
              For k = ele1 To ele2
                  ws.Cells(k, 1) = k
                  ws.Cells(k, 2) = Z
              Next k
          Rows(j + x + 1).EntireRow.Delete
          End If
    Next i
 Loop
```

#### Opcional, descrição da função definida por usuário(UDF)

Adiciona descrição da função para ser mostrada ao utilizá-la na planilha Excel.

```
Sub DescribeFunction()
   Dim FuncName As String
   Dim FuncDesc As String
   Dim Category As String
   Dim ArgDesc(1 To 3) As String

   FuncName = "EXTRACTELEMENT"
   FuncDesc = "Returns the nth element of a string that uses a separator character/Retorna o enésimo elemento da string que usa um caractér separador."
   Category = 7 'Text category
   ArgDesc(1) = "String that contains the elements/String que contém o elemento"
   ArgDesc(2) = "Element number to return/ Número do elemento a retornar"
   ArgDesc(3) = "Single-character element separator/ Elemento único separador (spc por padrão)"

   Application.MacroOptions _
      Macro:=FuncName, _
      Description:=FuncDesc, _
      Category:=Category, _
      ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

## Opcional

> Este código não realiza o que foi perguntado, por falta de atenção a
>   tarefa contrária foi escrita.Porém pode ser utilizado após o código do
>   Evert para agrupar e tornar planilhas muito grandes mais organizadas.

Este código primeiro reordena os dados da coluna B em ordem crescente, depois enumera na coluna A de 1 à última célula.
Após isso agrupa os dados.

Conforme a imagem 
[image: Exemplo]

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
rLastA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
rLastB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    On Error Resume Next
    .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
    .Rows.Ungroup
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(rLastB, 2))
End With

Range("B1").Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

For i = 1 To 4
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = i
Next i
Range("A1:A4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & rLastB)

    With r
        'identify common groups in column B
        j = 1
        v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                ' Colum B changed, create group
                v = .Cells(i, 1)
                If i > j + 1 Then
                    .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
                End If
                j = i
                v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' create last group
        If i > j + 1 Then
            .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
        End If
        ' collapse all groups
        .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

## A seguir serão divididos cada parte do código para melhor entendê-lo

**Desagrupamento**

É realizado para reordenar corretamente a coluna B

```
With ws
    On Error Resume Next
    .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
    .Rows.Ungroup
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(rLastB, 2))
End With
```

**Ordenação**

Usa o Range.Sort para ordenar os valores da coluna B, este código foi retirado [deste link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/277891-sorting-rows-ascending-order-based-column-b-vba.html)

```
Range("B1").Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

**Enumeração**

Enumera até a última linha com o Autofill, a ferramenta de preenchimento automático do Excel, em que após selecionar o Range, dois cliques são dados no ponto preto do canto inferior da seleção

```
For i = 1 To 4
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = i
Next i
Range("A1:A4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & rLastB)
```

**Agrupamento**

Este [código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824529/group-rows-by-value) foi retirado do SO Global e realiza o agrupamento

```
    With r
        'identify common groups in column B
        j = 1
        v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                ' Colum B changed, create group
                v = .Cells(i, 1)
                If i > j + 1 Then
                    .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
                End If
                j = i
                v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' create last group
        If i > j + 1 Then
            .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
        End If
        ' collapse all groups
        .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    End With
```

Comment: Hahaha... Fica tranquilo! Estava tentando entender o que você queria dizer com a resposta. Obrigado pelo seu tempo de qualquer maneira. :)